# little brown bugs on trunk of majestic palm

Tags: houseplants

I was transplanting my 2 majestic palm. I noticed on the trunk under the dirt that there was little brown dots, im sure are some type of bug.  I'm not sure what they are or how to treat them. they're not doing real well, I don't want to lose them. I'm afraid they possibly can infect my other house plants and cause more issues. When I brought all my house plants in last fall I treated all for spider mites. Evidently the soapy water and showers didn't take care of the bugs on the palms. I've yet to check the other house plants. What are these little brown bugs on the trunk of my majestic palm, is it domed? I also have little white fuzzies on the leaves. HELP!! Do I need to worry about other plants? How do I treat them too?

[image]

Comment: Are these palms indoors?  Insects and disease are rarely the main problem.  Did you treat for spider mite without seeing spider mites?  Ugh.  Number one, forget about total control or eradication of anything.  Number two, few insects are 'bad guys'...Number three, we gotta know what you've done, what the environment has been, have you added anything to include fertilizer, are these plants planted in potting soil, bagged, sterilized potting soil?  What made you decide to treat for spider mite?  Pesticides always create more problems then they are meant to solve.  Always.

Comment: You can't tell anything from the picture, please provide a closeup of the bug